# ccomptr _appdomain createinstance returning the system can't find the file specified

Tags: c#, c++, .net-assembly

I am trying to create an object of Test.cs in assembly "MyAssembly" using the below code. It was working earlier and that setup was gone. Now I have created the new setup but the same thing is not working in my new environment : 
  Windows 2008 R2 (added to a domain)
  IIS 7.5
  SharePoint 2010
  .NET2

MyUtil.cpp:

```
...........................
...........................

CComPtr<_AppDomain>         spDefAppDomain;
CComPtr<_ObjectHandle>      spObjectHandle;

...........................
...........................

hr = spDefAppDomain->CreateInstance(

                        _bstr_t("MyAssembly"),
                        _bstr_t("a.b.Test"),
                        &spObjectHandle

                    );
```

It is failed to create an instance of Test class. The return value is 0x80070002 (The system can not find the file specified). Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The assembly name must be a fully qualified name.  Like "MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: I have the registry entry for this assembly as follows: MyAssembly,Version="1.0.3035.23337",Culture="neutral",PublicKeyToken="61BAD946F70F081B",ProcessorArchitecture="MSIL". Should I change my code for the Assembly name as per the registry entry, but this same code was working earlier on other machine.

Comment: I found the solution, after copying the MyAssembly.dll to system32 bit folder it started working. My installer is deploying this dll in SysWow64 folder. But I have to check why this dll needs to be copied to system32 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copying `MyAssembly.dll` to `system32` folder it started working. My installer is deploying this dll in `SysWow64` folder.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others